# How to properly display a list of year and interest rate increase?

Tags: c#

I want to know how to create an output of a list of each year interest rate increase using For Loop. Mine keeps looping and won't break.

```
        double deposited;
        double year;
        double interestRate;
        double calculation;

        Console.Write("Enter the amount of deposited: ");
        deposited = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the number of years: ");
        year = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the interest rate as a percentage of 1.0: ");
        interestRate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Year\t Balance");
        calculation = deposited * Math.Pow((1 + interestRate), year);

        for (int i = 0; i < calculation; i++)
        {
            for (int t = 1; t < year; t++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t {1:C}", t,
                calculation));                   
            }              
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop, it's just that it's really long due to your `calculation` variable and the way you calculate and use it. For example, if I deposit 100 for 10 years and 1.0 interest rate, the calculation loop will loop 102400 times. Considering it will loop 10 times inside the inner loop, it'll be 1024000 times `Console.WriteLine()` is called.

Considering you want a simple interest rate over years:

```
using System;

public class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
        int year;
        double deposited;
        double interestRate;

        Console.Write("Enter the amount of deposited: ");
        deposited = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the number of years: ");
        year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the interest rate as a percentage of 1.0: ");
        interestRate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Year\t Balance");

        for(int i = 0; i < year; i++){
          var balance = deposited + (deposited * interestRate * (i + 1));
          Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}", (i + 1), balance);
        }
  }
}
```

Note: to calculate 1% interest rate, input "0.01", for 10%, "0.1" and for 100% "1.0" and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.